# Was I not seen talking?

Tags: bug, status-declined, chat

This is just a minor logical error, but still.
It could be fixed by outputting `seen` as `min(seen, talked)` I assume.

[image: I talked in the blind]

This one is a bit worse:

[image]

Comment: Feed users are a special case.

Comment: @badp, I can understand that, but still. If it talked it was seen, I reckon.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yeah, the "seen" part is only updated about once a minute. I'm a bit *meh* on that, but technically you're not wrong :) Note that it's quite similar here on the site (your profile currently says "seen 13 minutes ago", but you asked this question 10 minutes ago and edited it 4 minutes ago).

You're right about the second part, system users shouldn't have their "seen" time displayed (and they're really not ever seen -- the thing 136 days was just a debugging test).